# Server and Client programs only connect on local host

Tags: java, sockets

So I'm new to network programming, and made a server program and a client program to connect to the server for a class project. The code below is what I used to connect the two programs

```
// SERVER SIDE CODE
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(60060);
Socket client = server.accept();
// do server stuff

// CLIENT SIDE CODE
int port = 60060;
String ip = "127.0.0.1";
// String ip = "10.227.50.95"; IP I would use if client is on different machine
Socket client = new Socket(ip, port);
// do client stuff
```

when I try to put the server on one machine, and the client on another machine (note this is on the same network), and change String ip to the ip of the machine running the server, my client freezes for a minute, and then throws an connection timed out exception, I used a debugger to find out that it is in fact my Socket that is freezing, and not a infinite loop somewhere. I also turned my firewall off on my machine with the server, and still found the same result. Can someone explain Sockets and ServerSockets? Because the documentation on them did not help me much.

Update:

I haven't had a chance to check if the changes I made to my firewall will work or not (the other machine is my friend's), but I have noticed when the server and client run on the same machine, I don't need internet for the two programs to communicate. Not sure is this is a sign of a problem, but figured it couldn't hurt to mention.

Comment: A firewall on the server is a likely cause of this problem.

Comment: Do you accept the connection request at the `Server side`?

Comment: yes, in my server I have "Socket client = server.accept();" to accept clients

Comment: `String ip = "162.345.94.10"` . Doesn't it seem to be an invalid ip address? `345` isn't allowed there.

Comment: that IP is made up, it may be invalid. My intention however is to show my problem, and I didn't think showing a real ip was nessecary, but if it will help, I edited my question to show a valid ip

Comment: Have you made an appropriate hole in the firewall on the server machine? That could easily be the problem...

Comment: can you try this from a terminal on the client machine: `telnet 10.227.50.95 60060`